# Transition property to everything except text within tag

Tags: html, css, transition

I'm curious if it's possible to have my hover transition effect work on everything in this tag excpet the text within tag. If this effect were to work as invisiouned the button of the tab will fade away but the name within the button would remain..

Here's my code thus far:

```
ul.nav a{
    z-index: 99999;
    position: relative;
    right: 20px;
    bottom: -5px;
    font-family:  "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 9px 15px 20px 15px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    background-color: #EAEAEA;
    text-decoration: none; 
    text-align: center;
    color: #333;
    transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

And the hover property:

```
ul a:hover{
    background-color: #8F8F8F;
    opacity: .10;
    transition: background-color opacity 1s ease-out;
}

       <ul class ="nav">
       <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="http://www.gmail.com">Portfolio</a></li>
       <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com">About</a></li>
       <li><a href= "http://www.Flickr.com">Blog</a></li>
       <li class="floatr"><a href="http://www.flickr.com">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how it should be done: Instead of changing the opacity of the element, use an `rgba` color format. This color format allows you to set the opacity in addition to just color, so you can set background opacity instead of element opacity. So, in the main styles (the styles before the hover), have `rgba(234,234,234,1)` instead of `#EAEAEA` for `background-color`, and then in the hover styles, have `rgba(143,143,143,0.1)` instead of `#8F8F8F`

Comment: I love to help! Also, I see you're pretty new to stackoverflow, when an answer answers your question completely, please click the small, green "check" just under the vote count. This marks the answer as "accepted", giving the answer-er 15 reputation and giving you 2